# background color float alignment

Tags: html, css

I have this code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/
Why isn't yellow color spread over all three elements? Considering all elements are inside the div tag.

```
<div id="whole">
<p id="p1">
header
</p>
<p id="p2">
paragraph
</p>
<p id="p3">
paragraph 2
</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#whole{
  background:yellow;
}
#p1,#p2,#p3{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect JS fiddle link

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: #whole lacks of height, and width property

Comment: #whole not wrapping all element. add float:left to #whole div or if you want full width then add float:left;width:100%;

Comment: Try it with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/hhr7u7np/
Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/